# Recover Macintosh HD from split volume

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, hard-drive-recovery

Based on this image: 
[image]

The first one being the DVD from which the Mac has been booted, and the second one the USB drive connected to it (with various partitions),

It seems that the macintosh HD has been split into 6 different drives, disk2-disk7, most of them with half MB of disk space more or less and one having 1MB of disk space. That is obviously not correct, as the macintosh HD had at least 200GB of space.

I assume that data cannot be recovered, and I'm good with it, but how can I get the old drive back to be able to install an OS in it?

---

**EDIT:**

The photo was taken when booting from a Mac OS installation DVD and in the disk utility the only drives appearing are the dvd and the usb, but none of those drives, even less the Macintosh hd as a whole.

Comment: I have no Mac to test this with, so posting as a comment, but... Just wiping the disk and doing a clean install should work. Basically start up from Internet Recovery (⌘)-R immediately after power on. Release the keys when you see the Apple logo. Wait for the utilities window. Open disk utility, erase the disk, quit disk utility. Next choose reinstall OS X, ...  Very easy if you assume that data cannot be recovered.

Comment: I am curious as to how the disk got in this state. If you do want to attempt a data recovery then it might help if you editted the post to include what you did between a working seting and this interesting configuration.

Comment: @Hennes The problem is that in the disk utility the only drives appearing are the dvd and the usb, but none of those drives, even less the Macintosh hd as a whole. The computer is my sister's and maybe he did install some malware that did this.

Comment: Even when booted from any recovery (internet, USB, DVD, whatever) ? Because the active disk is not supposed to show up when you are booted from it.

Comment: disk2 though disk7 are partitions created by the install DVD.

Comment: The image is from a Mac booted from a Mac OS installation disk. So the active disk is the DVD if I'm not mistaken, and no, there only appears those 2 disks, the USB and DVD, none of those 6 mysterious drives.

Comment: @fd0 So is there actually an unrecoverable HDD in the system?

Comment: The internal hard drive is not mounted. Since `diskutil` cannot discover the disk, I suspect that it is dead.